# Why are the same 24 results being shown

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a problem with putting order by acctname limit 1,3. It is showing the same results from the 1st page to the last page.

```
<?php
$_payrolldate = '2019-10-15';

$pagenum = 1;
$record_limit_per_page = 24;
$offset = ($pagenum-1) * $record_limit_per_page;

$sql_count = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM `tbl_payroll_charges` WHERE payroll_date='$_payrolldate'");
$total_records = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_count);
$total_records = $total_records['total_records'];


$total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $record_limit_per_page);

for ($pagenum = 1; $pagenum <= $total_no_of_pages; $pagenum++) {
    $sqlEmp = "SELECT 
        tbl_payroll_charges.acctname,
        tbl_payroll_charges.payroll_date,
        tbl_payroll_charges.branch,
        tbl_payroll_charges.date_happened,
        tbl_payroll_charges.personal_charges,
        tbl_payroll_charges.inventory_charges,
        tbl_payroll_charges.raw_material_charges,
        tbl_payroll_charges.infraction_charges,
        tbl_payroll_charges.other_charges,
        tbl_payroll_charges.total_charges
    FROM tbl_payroll_charges 
    WHERE payroll_date='$_payrolldate' 
    order by acctname ASC
    LIMIT $pagenum, $record_limit_per_page";
    $empResult = mysqli_query($db, $sqlEmp); 
    $final_total = 0;
    while($listemp = mysqli_fetch_array($empResult))  
    {
        echo $listemp['acctname']."<br>";
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it is showing same results on all pages. This code generates 37 pages, each page returns 24 rows, 24 rows fit in one legal size paper. When I removed the "order by acctname" it works well.

[the print layout before sending to the printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzCHT.png)

Comment: In `LIMIT $record_limit_per_page, $pagenum"` - shouldn't it be `($pagenum-1)*$record_limit_per_page`, otherwise it is just being 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Hi @NigelRen I need it that way for the page number of every page and that works well, My problem is inside the "for loop" thanks

Comment: 1) put `$offset = ($pagenum-1) * $record_limit_per_page;` inside loop, before `$sqlEmp="..."`. 
2) change query from `... LIMIT $pagenum, $record_limit_per_page` to `... LIMIT $offset, $record_limit_per_page`

Comment: @smashrain i was actually thinking of that because i am staring to my code since i posted this and analyzing it and thinking of the logic, i was actually working when i saw your comment and its right hahaha Thank you for making me realizing that it was right... thank you thank you very much you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

[The Final Image for Printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgE1V.png)
So to make a final answer, This is the final code and thanks to smashrain for making me realize that i am stoopid hahaha anyway i am trying to make my own crystal report using php and pure css only.

```
<?php
$_payrolldate = '2019-10-15';

$pagenum = 1;
$record_limit_per_page = 24;

$sql_count = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM `tbl_payroll_charges` WHERE payroll_date='$_payrolldate'");
$total_records = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_count);
$total_records = $total_records['total_records'];


$total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $record_limit_per_page);

for ($pagenum = 1; $pagenum <= $total_no_of_pages; $pagenum++) {

$offset = ($pagenum-1) * $record_limit_per_page;

$sqlEmp = "SELECT 
    tbl_payroll_charges.acctname,
    tbl_payroll_charges.payroll_date,
    tbl_payroll_charges.branch,
    tbl_payroll_charges.date_happened,
    tbl_payroll_charges.personal_charges,
    tbl_payroll_charges.inventory_charges,
    tbl_payroll_charges.raw_material_charges,
    tbl_payroll_charges.infraction_charges,
    tbl_payroll_charges.other_charges,
    tbl_payroll_charges.total_charges
FROM tbl_payroll_charges 
WHERE payroll_date='$_payrolldate' 
order by acctname ASC
LIMIT $offset, $record_limit_per_page";
$empResult = mysqli_query($db, $sqlEmp); 
$final_total = 0;
while($listemp = mysqli_fetch_array($empResult))  
{
    echo $listemp['acctname']."<br>";
}
}
```